# Task Scheduler failed to start

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

Last weekend I came across **Launch Failure** in the windows task scheduler. The details are as below -

```
> Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational Source:    
> Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler Date:          6/24/2012 1:14:16 PM
> Event ID:      101 Task Category: Task Start Failed Level:        
> Error Keywords:      (1) User:          SYSTEM Computer:      Some
> Computer Name Description: Task Scheduler failed to start "some file
> path" task for user "author". Additional Data: Error Value:
> 2147549186. Event Xml: <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">  
> <System>
>     <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler" Guid="{DE7B24EA-73C8-4A09-985D-5BDADCFA9017}" />
>     <EventID>101</EventID>
>     <Version>0</Version>
>     <Level>2</Level>
>     <Task>101</Task>
>     <Opcode>101</Opcode>
>     <Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords>
>     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-06-24T20:14:16.003204300Z" />
>     <EventRecordID>2091795</EventRecordID>
>     <Correlation />
>     <Execution ProcessID="936" ThreadID="812" />
>     <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational</Channel>
>     <Computer>Some Computer Name</Computer>
>     <Security UserID="" />   </System>   <EventData Name="TaskStartFailedEvent">
>     <Data Name="TaskName">some file path</Data>
>     <Data Name="UserContext">author</Data>
>     <Data Name="ResultCode">2147549186</Data>   </EventData> </Event>
```

First, what is the meaning of error code **"Error Value: 2147549186"**.
Second, what could be the reason for this issue.
 
Finally, what is the resolution for the issue.

My heartiest thanks in advance for the replies :)

Comment: I found post which enlisted all error code and description, here is the meaning of 2147549186 - Call was canceled by the message filter.

reference - 
http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/i18n-bel-svn/2010-November/000020.html

Comment: Though still dont have the answer for my questions :(

Comment: I am not sure if this is the only source of that error code but it looks like it is RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED.  This is a pretty generic error message that can occur under a wide variety of situations where your code is calling out to or consuming external resources.  Almost impossible to help without knowing what the job you are running as a scheduled task is trying to do.

Comment: implementation of the scheduled task is a .exe is run via batch file. The .exe fetches values from a asp api object call and refreshes a local DB.
The scheduled task runs every 1 hour, six out of seven days it runs without problem.
One more think is there any log that might be associated with windows task, if so how do i fetch it?

Answer (score 13):

So I just had the same issue on my server after changing the password for the account that the tasks were run under.
To solve I made a change to the task settings that required me to re-enter the account password.

Comment: this worked for me. I changed my Active Directory password the day before, and I was the user set as the task's Run As User

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same error code. You can have a try on change following.
=== quote start ===
in task scheduler, click on the scheduled job properties >>> then settings

in the last listed option:
"if the task is already running, the following rule appplies:"
select "stop the existing instance" from the drop down list.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/task-scheduler-failed-to-start-additional-data/96994b77-d690-4403-8b51-4e1d0ae998e1